# Substring dictionary attribute name in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have a below dictionary:

```
{
    "dev/pw": "pw",
    "dev/user": "temp",
}
```

I wanted to transform it into below:

```
{
    "pw": "pw",
    "user": "temp",
}
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Not so sure if you can change an existing dictionary keys but you can create a new dictionary from the existing one with required transformation like:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    nd: "{{ nd | default({}) | combine (tmp) }}"
  vars:
    tmp: "{ '{{ item.key | replace('dev/','') }}' : '{{ item.value }}' }"
  loop: "{{ d | dict2items }}"
```

`nd` will result to:

```
"nd": {
    "pw": "pw",
    "user": "temp"
}
```